# Google Translator HotKeys

Tags: google-translate

I'm talking about the [Google Translator on web](http://translate.google.com/), I use this tool a lot every day, with several languages. Anyone knows if there are hotkeys or shortcuts to help and get faster the user experience?, thanks in advance.

Comment: any particular hot key function you are after?

Comment: how did it go, did you find any of the solutions helpful? or managed to find something better? =)

Comment: Yep, both solutions were helpful. Thanks a lot. I'm already using the free chrome extension "Google Transkate Hotkey".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or tools used for programming.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you prefer the Google Translator on the web, there are plugins you can install to add shortcuts.
Here are some of them:

- Google Translate Hotkey: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-translate-hotkey/lhfibdjmgcoeokogjlbikafjeplnajfp?hl=en
- Keyboard shortcut for Google Trans: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keyboard-shortcuts-for-go/akjhnbnjanndggbcegmdggfjjclohjpo?hl=en (as mentioned by yama)

Alternatively, you can use the google translator toolkit:
http://googletranslate.blogspot.com.au/2010/08/translate-faster-with-keyboard.html

Or there are also a number of other extensions you can install to help what you need to do:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search-extensions/google%20translator?hl=en

Answer (score 8):

If you use Google Chrome, this extension may be useful to you.

[Keyboard Shortcuts for Google Translate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keyboard-shortcuts-for-go/akjhnbnjanndggbcegmdggfjjclohjpo?hl=ja)

It allows to use keyboard shortcut for Google Translate on Web.

[Option] + [0-7] keys are bound to each indexed button.

- lang-swap button -> Option + 0
- button1 -> Option + 1
- button2 -> Option + 2
- button3 -> Option + 3
- button4 -> Option + 4
- button5 -> Option + 5
- button6 -> Option + 6
- button7 -> Option + 7